# Is it possible to trigger an iMacros script using a Google form?

Tags: google-apps-script, imacros, google-forms

My goal is to fill in a Google form and then have the Google Apps script trigger an iMacros script in the browser that will take the data from the form and use it to complete a task. I know that you can use Google Apps Script to make a request to fetch a URL using [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app. And I know that you can launch a iMacros macro from terminal using: firefox "imacros://run/?m=my_macro.iim"

So is there a way to trigger an iMacros script to run using a Google form?

Comment: Apps Script code (e.g. `UrlFetchApp`) runs in Google's servers, not your browser. Further, Apps Scripts written for Google Forms are only available when in "edit" mode, not "respond" mode.

Comment: I managed a work around by having the data in the Google Sheet (populated by the Google Form) publish the data on the web using Google Apps Script>Publish>Deploy as web app... This published the data that was entered into the form on the web at the URL given. Then iMacros can be scheduled to visit that URL at a given time. The iMacros script scrapes the data and acts on it. It is not immediate, like a trigger would be. I have the iMacros script run once daily. But I guess you could trigger the iMacros script every hour or more often to make it work more like an immediate trigger.

Comment: @LawrenceofArabia thanks for the info about Kantu. I'm going to look at that.